# How do I remove this ambiguity in hybrid inheritance?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a case in project where I need to inherit an abstract class virtually into two different classes which are again inherited into final class but the compiler keeps showing me this error

```
 error C2250: 'D': ambiguous inheritance of 'B &A::doit(void)'
```

How do I remove such error , class sample is as follow

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual A& doit() = 0;
};

class B :virtual public A {
public:
    virtual B& doit() {
        cout << "B";
        return *this;
    }
};
class C : virtual public A {
public:
    C& doit() {
        cout << "C";
        return *this;
    }
};
class D : public B, public C {
public:
    D& doit() {
        cout << "D";
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I have tried deleting base class functions first but it does not seem to work.

Comment: If you can return `A&` from all `doit()`s (i.e. avoid covariant return), it will solve the issue.

Comment: @wohlstad I need to use covariant return too at times

Comment: You seem to be using MSVC. It used to be a known bug long time ago :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933061/c-ambiguous-inheritance-error-in-vs-2010. Maybe it's still there. BTW - gcc accepts your code, and so is clang.

Comment: What's your compiler and the compiler flags you're using? I tried it with C++20 and calling `doit` from a `D` object and it works fine?

Comment: Checking with C++20 - live - https://godbolt.org/z/orqn769od as @wohlstad says just MSVC fails to compile this clang and GCC compile ok.

Comment: @NathanFurnal Its msvc , in visual studio, looking at  project settings , version of compiler seems to be iso c++14 standard

Comment: @user19783152 Others have been faster, it's an MSVC problem.